# Is Lenovo Z560 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, lenovo-laptop

Is Lenovo Z560 (59-048876) **32-bit** or **64-bit**?

I could only find that it has Win7 Home Premium.

> Processor: Intel Core i5 460M
>   Speed: 2.53 GHZ
>   RAM: 4 GB
>   HDD: 500 GB
>   Screen: 15.6"

Comment: Seems to be 64-bit Intel® Core™ i5-480M Processor ( 2.66GHz 1066MHz 3MB ) http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=52952

Comment: It's getting less and less common for suppliers to install a 32-bit version of Windows these days.  Practically every mainstream processor is 64-bit and there are little to no real world applications that are not 64-bit compatible, and if you do have a problem then it's easy to virtualize a 32-bit guest.  The only time that people tend to have a problem with 64-bit Windows is when they have old hardware.  Chances are it would be a 64-bit OS installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Core i5m 460 is a [64-bit processor](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=50179)

> **Instruction Set:**  64-bit

---

And comes with [a 64-bit OS](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/notebooks/ideapad/z-series/z560)

> **Operating system:** Genuine Windows 7 Home Premium 64

So yes, it's a full 64-bit system